# Javascript sticky menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with Sticky-menu. I'm trying to get it work. Once I scroll down the page, I want my **Sticky Menu** go under **Main Fixed Menu**

```js
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();
scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);

  function stickIt() {
  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
   orgElement = $('.original');
   coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
   leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
   widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');

   $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
   $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
  } else {
   $('.cloned').hide();
   $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="logo">Main Fixed Menu</div>
  <div class="intro">Some content</div>
  <div class="menu">Sticky-menu</div>
</header>
```

Comment: [You don't need javascript for menus.](https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/xhiJH) You may want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: can you create fiddle